# Image brightness handling by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I increase/decrease the brightness of the image by using jQuery?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the brightness of an image with CSS filters and modify the CSS with jQuery like this:

HTML

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" />
```

Javascript

```
var bLevel = 1;
$('img').click(function() {
    bLevel += .1;
    $(this).css({"-webkit-filter" : "brightness("+bLevel+")"})
});
```

(demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/ZeY8C/1/))

Increase/decrease brightness on click demo: http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/ZeY8C/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the opacity of the image, like:

```
$("#my-image").css("opacity", "0.5");
```